# Как в Group Box сделать не кликабельные кнопки?

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос такой, при входе через 1 форму у меня есть 3 пользователя:
1.Админ
2.Мастер
3.Клиент
Каким образом можно сделать так чтобы панель элементов Group Box и находящиеся в нем кнопки были не кликабельные?
Частичка кода:

```
public MainForm(int x)
        {
            
            string status;
            InitializeComponent();
            switch (x)
            {
                case 1: status = "Вы зашли как: Администратор";
                    label1.Text = status;
                    break;
                case 2: status = "Вы зашли как: Мастер";
                    label1.Text = status;
                    break;
                case 3: status = "Вы зашли как: Клиент";
                    label1.Text = status;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Ну суть в том, что допустим можно сделать `groupbox1.Visible==false;`, но это не совсем то, что я хотел увидеть. Хочется чтобы оно не исчезало, а просто не кликалось.

[image: 1]

Comment: `Enabled = false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не пишите свой код в конструкторе окна, используйте обработчик события `Form.Load`. В конструкторе допускается только запись полученных в аргументы данных в поля или свойства класса. Конструктор должен выполняться максимально быстро и не должен содержать кода, способного вызвать исключение.

Используйте runtime структуры данных для того, что может изменяться, нарример словарь `Dictionary<>`. Например, вдруг вы захотите добавить еще одну роль, тогда придется переписывать код. Роли можно сохранить например в бд. Для каждой роли можно выделить список привелегий, при это интерфейс должен будет реагировать именно на привелегии у роли, а не на роль. Но это на будущее.

Чтобы отключить взаимодействие с контролом, используйте свойство `Control.Enabled`.

Если оставить то, что есть, то можно завести такой словарик.

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, string> _roleNames = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    [1] = "Администратор",
    [2] = "Мастер",
    [3] = "Клиент"
};

private readonly int _currentRole;

public MainForm(int role)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _currentRole = role;
}

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = $"Вы зашли как: {_roleNames[_currentRole]}";
    groupbox1.Enabled = _currentRole < 3; // 1 и 2
    groupbox2.Enabled = _currentRole < 2; // только 1
}
```

Comment: Хорошая мысль, связанная с "Конструктор должен выполняться максимально быстро и не должен содержать кода, способного вызвать исключение". Где ж были эта фраза где-то года 2 назад, когда я писал в конструктор почти весь код (вызов методов и тд) :D   Отличный ответ!